# Create a polygon of the inner most area of three polygons using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-pro, overlapping-features

I have three polygons and I would like to create an extra polygon that represents the inner most boundary of all three without tracing manually so a GP tool or GP tool steps is/are required. The image shows the extent I would like to have represented by a polygon.

[image]

Comment: Union the three layers, and select out the geometry where the OIDs for all three sources are not -1.

Comment: You're describing the intersection of three polygons. If they're on different layers, you can use the intersection geo-processing algorithm.

Comment: Yep, I think I had a bit of a mental lapse. Just running intersect on all three did the job.